# Doctrine ManyToOne creates foregin keys and uniqe index

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating a dinner planner and have a 'list' object where all the weekdays have its own field. I have added a ManyToOne relation in it for the recipe like this:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MatAppen\FrontendBundle\Entity\Recipe")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tuesday_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $tuesday;
```

The joinColumn statement is apparently not necessary, and have tried without with the same results.

My problem is that Doctrine is adding a Uniqe index and a foreign key on this field (and all of the same type), that results in a recipe only beeing available for 1 user.

Any idea how the entity should look instead?
This is the output from doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

```
ALTER TABLE lists ADD CONSTRAINT FK_8269FA55B974FE2 FOREIGN KEY (tuesday_id) REFERE
CREATE INDEX IDX_8269FA55B974FE2 ON lists (tuesday_id);
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated :)

SQL error looks like this:

```
1062: Duplicate entry '122' for key 'UNIQ_8269FA521671777'
```

## Edit

What I *think* I want is a Many-To-One Unidirectional relationship. The reason is that the column/property tuesday is only supposed to have one recipe, but my recipe is not supposed to be aware of any of my lists...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `@ORM\ManyToOne` and you should be using `@ORM\ManyToMany`

Comment: But I only want one recipe for that field in my list entity?

Comment: Did you inverse your relation in your other entity? Check 5.4 here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: I Thanks, yes, that is the place I have been reading. What I **think** I want is a Many-To-One unidirectional relationship. I dont need the recipe to know about the list, and tuesday is only supposed to have one recipe... (I will update the **question** to clear it up)...

Comment: In that case, i suggest reading this: http://www.krueckeberg.org/notes/d2.html#onendashtondashmany-unidirectional-with-join-table

Comment: This is exactly what I want: http://www.krueckeberg.org/notes/d2.html#manyndashtondashone-unidirectional but doctrine creates a unique constraint :-\